# Euclidean distance and turn cost

Tags: euclidean-geometry, computational-geometry

Does the shortest path from an initial point to a goal point, in an environment with obstacles, also gives the minimum sum of turning angles?

It doesn't seem to be obvious, but I couldn't come up with a counter example!
If it is indeed true, is there a proof which states that?

Note: the shortest path means minimum sum of Euclidean distance. 
Additional context: I was using A* on a visibility graph to find the optimal path. Two different cost functions were used. 1. Just the Euclidean distance and 2. Euclidean distance + theta, turning angle, multiplied by some constant.

[image: Shortest path, which also gives the minimum sum of turning angles]

Comment: I don't think so.  I was able to generate a setting in which the turning angles through the shortest path was 180 degrees, but through the longest path was less.  I'll try to make an image and show you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following image, constructed by the original poster, demonstrates that the claim is false.  The shortest path (green) has a larger total turning angle than the longer path (red).

[image]

Comment: Please see this link http://imgur.com/a/HXR27
The green line appears to be the shortest path and it also gives the minimum sum of turning angles. Am I missing something? Also, the shortest path is aways through the vertices of the obstacle.

Comment: I made the image imprecisely.  If you move the square down so that it touches the rectangle, then I believe my turning angles are still correct.  I know that the shortest path should be through the vertices, but I lack the paint skills to do it :-P

Comment: Great! I think that works. I shall double check and get back.

Comment: I've edited the figure to demonstrate

Comment: You can use this http://imgur.com/a/2Zdx7 image for a clearer answer and I shall accept it.

Comment: It's a very interesting problem, though.  I wonder what the 'shortest' path would look like if your *only* goal were to minimize turning angle?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49862/discussion-between-saurav-and-michael-stachowsky).